# How to create a symfony 2 search filter base on the multiple tables entities

Tags: php, symfony, search, filter, dql

I want to build a search filter in symfony.  I am using symfony 2.8. I have four table with respected entities. 
Table are

```
professional
professional_pets
professional_categories
professional_organization
```

`professional_pets` table contain `professionalId` and `petId` for store the relation pet and professional.
same way the `professional_categories` table contains `professionalId` and `categoryId` fields to store relation between `professional` and `Categories`. Same case with `professional_organization`.

What I want that I want a dql query to filter professionals form professionals table if it is possible which can extract only those records from professional table which have relation with specific in professional_pet, professional_categories and professional_organizations.
In other work I want tho create filter for professinals in professionals table base on the if there is a relation sotre for them in professional_pet, professional_categories and professional_organizations tables.

I am attaching a snapshot of filter. Thanks for help in advance.
[image]

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: I did not getting right point to try. I can put a function in professionalRepository to search.  The only problem for me is to write a dql for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

```
<?php

namespace CommonBundle\Entity\Children;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;


class professionalRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function findAllBySearch($searchValues)
    {
        /** @var QueryBuilder $query */
        //professional entity
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');

        if(!empty($searchValues['pet_id'])){
            $query->join('AppBundle:ProfessionalPets', 'pp', 'WITH', 'pp.professionalId = p.id');
            $query->andWhere('pp.petId = :pet_id')
                ->setParameter('pet_id', $searchValues['pet_id']);
        }
        if(!empty($searchValues['cat_id'])){
            $query->join('AppBundle:ProfessionalCategories', 'pc', 'WITH', 'pc.professionalId = p.id');
            $query->andWhere('pc.categoryId = :cat_id')
                ->setParameter('cat_id', $searchValues['cat_id']);
        }
        if(!empty($searchValues['org_id'])){
            $query->join('AppBundle:ProfessionalOrganization', 'po', 'WITH', 'po.professionalId = p.id');
            $query->andWhere('po.organizationId = :org_id')
                ->setParameter('org_id', $searchValues['org_id']);
        }

        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Since I don't know what your bundles and entity classes names are, you will need to modify them.

Comment: If you do !empty(...) you don't have to do array_key_exists(...) - empty() will do all the work.

Comment: It's pretty good described in question what entities involved into search - why do you put your own code without any change? Without changes your code is irrelevant.

Comment: I have no much experience with dql. So actually I want to also know that where the reference in query for each table is put. How it works.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I have changed the code to Muhammads case.

Comment: Thanks both of you very much.